# Index.html file generated by apidoc.js shows a 404 error after deploying asp.net web api app to server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, api-doc

I used [apidocjs](http://apidocjs.com) to setup the documentation of my asp.net web api app. Everything works fine on my machine when I run my web api in visual studio but not on the server I deployed the app to.
 I get a 404 error when I navigate to the index.html generated by apidocjs.
 I think it's an issue with IIS.

I need suggestions on how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found the problem kind of silly.

I did not include the ~ symbol as part of the path in my anchor tag.
Before I had

I added ~

```html
<li><a href="/service-doc/index.html">Docs</a></li>

<li><a href="~/service-doc/index.html">Docs</a></li>
```

and problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

Update.

What I did earlier solved the problem on the deployment i did to my local IIS but not on my remote server.

I had move my static html file into the Content folder of my web-api, edited the link to look like this and the problem was resolved.

```html
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Content/doc/index.html")">Docs</a>
```

Got this from here. [Ordinary html links in mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339255/ordinary-html-links-in-mvc-razor)